# D3 arc and SVG 2d to 3d perspective change

Tags: animation, d3.js, svg, transition

I have a SVG with group of independent arcs that move around common origin. On user event those arcs can change both their radii and start/end angles. On other user event the user can change view from 2d to fake 3d (orthographic?) via following css transform, as described [here](https://beta.observablehq.com/d/190a4518cada1873):

```
translate(0px, ${t*5 - i*t*40}px)
rotateX(${t*60}deg)
rotateZ(${t*-30}deg)
scale(1.0)
```

t is a boolean flag telling if perspective view is on or off, if flag = 0 then no actual transformation is made.

My code that illustrate the example can be viewed here: https://codepen.io/stopyransky/pen/MZPbjg

Once you click button to trigger perspective view it changes correctly, but arc transitions (radii/angle) are now messed up.

My question is how to fix so the transitions of arcs will remain correct? I assume I need to modify the functions that change how arc is build in tweenAngles and tweenRadii but I have no clue what those transitions should be. I tried to reverse transitions when flag is 0 but it does not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After discussion on [Animation at Work slack channel](https://animationatwork.slack.com) and help of channel's user 'mamboleoo' I am able to provide answer for my question.

First problem was using `node.style.transition = "ease 1s all";` inside `togglePerspective` function. Without it paths are animated correctly in 3d view but we miss transition between 2d and 3d view on button click.

To fix it we need to create custom d3.styleTween in `togglePerspective`:

```
function togglePerspective() {
  perspective = !perspective;

  d3.selectAll('path').each((d, i, n) => {
    const node = n[i];
    // OLD
    // node.style.transition = "ease 1s all";
    // node.style.transform = perspectiveTween(perspective, i);

    node.style.transformOrigin = "20% 20%";

    // NEW LINES
    const tr = d3.transition().duration(3000);

    d3.select(node).transition(tr)
      .styleTween('transform', () => {
        return function(time) { // interpolation fn (time = 0...1)
          return perspectiveTween(perspective, i, time);
        }
      }); 
  });
}
```

where in `perspectiveTween` function we parameterize previously fixed values of the transform:

```
function perspectiveTween(perspective, i, time) {
  const T = perspective ? time : (1-time);
  const xRotation = (60 * T);
  const yRotation = (-30 * T);

  const yTranslation = (T*5) - i*(T * 10);

  return `
    translate(0px, ${yTranslation}px)
    rotateX(${xRotation}deg)
    rotateZ(${yRotation}deg)
    scale(1.0)`
};
```

working example: https://codepen.io/stopyransky/pen/NZdawR